# Cant find the exe of mysqldump

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

I'm just learning about MYSQL after 6 years focusing only on sql server(dumb me).

I'm studying about how backups works there, but I can't find the `mysqldump` file to execute the backup. on DOS it says the command is not recognized and i cant find it to use the full patch in the command line.

is it something that should be download apart?

and also as we are here. with SQL Server we create a physical file for the backup. with MYSQL if i'm not mistaken, we create a DUMP FILE that has the "commands" to insert data and create objects again, right?

Comment: can you also tell us, which operating system you use

Comment: Sorry, Windows 10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is stored where all binaries are from MySQL Server (if you didn't change the default location)

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin
```

And yes MySQL creates a sql file(dump), depending on the options you can have different commands like triggers and so on includes or excluded.

for a complete list of options always read up on the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html)

Comment: Ohh thanks man, I was looking in another directory. it created a lot of directories and it was a bit confusing to me.  I was looking in program data.

Comment: dude, thanks. Been a while looking for this